# Standard deviation: calculating how polarizing a question is

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

I'm trying to calculate how polarizing a question is.
Let's say I have a question that has 3 possible choices.
A certain percentage of people choose a specific answer.

Answer a: $30\%$
Answer b: $50\%$
Answer c: $20\%$

I was thinking I could try to calculate the standard deviation. But since the answers are not assigned to a certain value I'm not sure how to apply the formula. Maybe someone can help me here?

Comment: See Standard deviation of Multinomial distribution. To calculate standard deviation you should determine the sample size and probability of success  (probability of correct choice).

Comment: There is no correct choice though :)

Comment: In three choices a,b, and c which one is correct answer?

Comment: do I need to specify a "correct answer" for this to work? Because in reality there is no correct answer. It's a question about an opinion.

Comment: There are two ways, first: choose the favorable choice. Second: calculate standard deviation for each choice separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of 'measures of diversity' (see Wikipedia).
Perhaps the simplest is called the **Simpson Index** (often denoted $\lambda$).

It is the
sum of squares of relative frequencies for the categories.
In your case: $$\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^3 r_i^2 = .3^2 + .5^2 + .2^2 =  .38.$$

Very roughly speaking, this is the probability that two people
chosen at random from the population would have matching views as
to the correct choice A, B, or C. Notice that $1/K \le \lambda \le 1,$ where $K$ is the number of categories, here three. Smaller values of $\lambda$ indicate greater diversity.

If you want test whether all three categories are equally popular (probability 1/3 each), you might do a **chi-squared goodness-of-fit test** of that null hypotheses. For that, you would need to know
the total number of people involved. (If $n = 100,$ the chi-squared statistic is 14.0 > 5.99, and the null hypothesis is rejected; if $n = 30,$ the chi-squared statistic is 4.2 < 5.99, and it is not rejected. In your case, the chi-squared statistic is 
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{(nr_i - n/3)^2}{n/3}.$$
which has approximately a chi-squared distribution with DF = 3-1=2.
The 'critical value', separating rejection and not, is the 95th quantile of that distribution, 5.99.

Comment: For (much) more about measuring diversity see:  https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/10/measuring_diversity.html